# I'm new to and and ran into a little trouble with a learning project I'm working on

Tags: mysql, sql

> ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near 'NOT NULL,
> -- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

I don't understand what I did wrong?

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema filmKategory
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema filmKategory
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `filmKategory` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci ;
USE `filmKategory` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `filmKategory`.`category`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `filmKategory`.`category` (
  `category_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`));


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `filmKategory`.`new_table`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `filmKategory`.`new_table` (
  `ıd`  INT NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `price` (10,0) INT NOT NULL,
  `images` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `Stock` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT '5',
  `Category` VARCHAR(2000) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `category_category_id` INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ıd`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `ıd_UNIQUE` (`ıd` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_new_table_category_idx` (`category_category_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_new_table_category`
    FOREIGN KEY (`category_category_id`)
    REFERENCES `filmKategory`.`category` (`category_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 33
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4
COLLATE = utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Comment: Mysql is different than SQL Server. They are different products by different companies. I corrected your tags for you because of this.

Comment: Try `\`price\` INT NOT NULL`. (Not sure what the (10,0) was supposed to before?

Comment: @ADyson I think it's a mix of wanting a decimal and implementing an INT?

Comment: if you want to have decimals in the field try `price DECIMAL(10,0) NOT NULL`

Comment: @Sam020 good point, could be either. OP needs to decide what they actually want.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Which query throws that error?